# Number of total countries in Google Analytics is around 230 while google search says total number of countries is 197

Tags: google-analytics, countries

Number of total countries in Google Analytics is around 230 while google search says total number of countries is 197.

How to explain this?

On my one site total number of countries according to Google Analytics is around 214. When I told this to a guy he simply said Google Search says total number of countries is 197 (I also checked it). I had no explaination for this.

Comment: It’s complicated, and not really a matter of programming. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states#Criteria_for_inclusion

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to belong on [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well..I will argue opposite to that. As API developer I use GA APIs and the results (number of countries) returned is not matching my general knowledge. Hence this question becomes relevant in the context of programming.

Answer (score 4):

Google Analytics countries report is based on 249 current *ISO-3166-1 alpha-2* codes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see more results than countries on your dashboard is because Google Analytics counts also visits from territories as well (example Antarctica which is not a country)